# Easy JAVA questions. But hard for me

Tags: java, string, char

When the first character of word starts with 'A' or 'a', let the program output the word 'America'. if the first character of the word starts with other characters, let the program prints "error"

```
public class Home1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str=args[0];
        char ch;
        ch=   (1)   .    (2)    ;           
       if(      (3)      ) System.out.println("America");
          (4)    System.out.println("Error");
        }
}
```

I have figured out that 4th one is 'else' 
3rd one may be something like, 'first character = 'a','A'

but i do not fully get them.

could you help me?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt know about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thanks for editing it in stead of me, this is my first time to use this site. Unfortunately, those are the all the information that I have got. let me fix the question a bit. '
When the first character of command line factor starts with 'A' or 'a', let the program output the word...' This is all I can say... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(1) and (2): get somehow the char at position 0 of the string read.  Documentation of the available methods on Strings is available here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

(3) Compare the character read with 'A' and 'a':

If char equals 'A' or char equals 'a'....
Documentation can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok this looks like a code fill in the blanks,

Your actual code should be something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = args[0];
    char ch;
    ch = str.charAt(0);
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A')
        System.out.println("America");
    else
        System.out.println("Error");
}
```

So,

```
(1) = str
(2) = charAt(0)
(3) = ch == 'a' || ch == 'A'
(4) = else
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, let me guess the flow. the first one is, since I put a word, I need to use string, at the same time I need to identity the first character of the word, i need to use char. since I need to verify the first character, I need to put '0' in a bracket. 3rd one is ch == 'a' and ch =='A'. Am I right?